# in SQLite, how to do a Join avoiding specific duplicates in a column

Tags: sqlite, join

I’m trying to extract, from a SQLite database, a set of records using a join, avoiding duplicates in one column. The problem is as follows: I have two tables, Table_A has multiple “Names” for the same row in Table_B, but I only need the first name (order by Table_A.Id). So, in the example below, I only want Alfa and Gamma in my results.

Here is an example:

**Table _A**

```
   Id      bId     Name
   -----   ------  ----
   1       1       Alfa
   2       1       Beta
   3       2       Gamma
   4       2       Delta
```

**Table_B**

```
   Id      Year    Title
   -----   ------  ------
   1       1900    Doctor
   2       1920    Priest
```

The result that I’m looking for is,

```
   bId      Name    Year    Title
   ------   ------  -----   ------
   1        Alfa    1900    Doctor
   2        Gamma   1920    Priest
```

The obvious join is as follows:

```
Select  bID, Name, Year, Title from Table_A as a join Table_B as b on b.id=a.bid 
order by bId;
```

Which return the following data, including beta and delta, which I don’t need.

```
   bId     Name    Year    Title
   -----   ------  ------  ------
   1       Alfa    1900    Doctor
   1       Beta    1900    Doctor
   2       Gamma   1920    Priest
   2       Delta   1920    Priest
```

If I change the query to

```
Select  bID, Name, Year, Title from Table_A as a join Table_B as b on b.id=a.bid 
group by bId order by bId;
```

Then I get something like this result that is also wrong (I get Beta & Delta instead of Alfa & Gamma)

```
   bId     Name    Year    Title
   -----   ------  ------  ------
   1       Beta    1900    Doctor
   2       Delta   1920    Priest
```

Which is not good either.

I have tried to find how to do this in SQLite, by looking at the syntax and using Google, and had been unable to find an answer. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT bID, Name, Year, Title 
 FROM Table_A AS A INNER JOIN Table_B AS B on B.id = A.bid 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE bid = A.bid AND id < A.id)
 ORDER BY bId;
```

This filters the results keeping only the records for which a lower `id` value cannot be found for the same `bid` value.  Not highly-performant but in the case of not-huge tables it may be sufficiently quick for your needs.

Alternatively:

```
 SELECT bID, Name, Year, Title 
 FROM Table_A AS A INNER JOIN Table_B AS B on B.id = A.bid 
 WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM Table_A WHERE bid = A.bid)
 ORDER BY bId;
```

Comment: They both worked well. Second alternative gives an error on Id (third line), but it is very easy to fix by using A.id instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can select which record in a group is returned by using MIN or MAX.
In this query, add `MIN(A.Id)` to the SELECT clause.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "Error while executing query: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: Modifing the statement as "Select bId, Name, Year, Title, MIN(Table_A.Id) as x from Table_A as a join Table_B as b on b.id=a.bid group by bId order by bId;" gives the following error: "Error while executing query: no such column: Table_A.Id". So, I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the table alias `a`.